# show Image after loading is completed in Angular

Tags: angular

I read full image src with API from server.But I want that image not to be displayed until it is completely loaded and to display the skeleton instead while loading images are displayed in sections and I want the skeleton to be destroyed when the image is fully displayed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install package:npm i ngx-skeleton-loader.

Try the below code:

```html
HTML:
<div class="col-12 p-0">
    <ngx-skeleton-loader *ngIf="!contentLoaded" appearance="circle" [theme]="{ width: '80px', height: '80px' }">
    </ngx-skeleton-loader>

    <div *ngIf="contentLoaded" class="content-loaded">
        <img
src="//user-images.githubusercontent.com/1252570/96255429-9e7e7a00-1002-11eb-9471-1e7fdfc139cd.png"
alt=""
class="content-loaded-image"
/>
</div>
 </div>
 
 TS:
  contentLoaded = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.contentLoaded = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
```